# Manhwa where the main character is executed by her father and then wakes up a few days/months earlier

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, reincarnation

I'm looking for a story similar to one described in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260148/manhwa-where-the-female-main-character-is-killed-by-her-family-and-reincarnated). I don't believe it is *Who Made Me a Princess*, because the main character (MC) wasn't blonde and father was horrible to her.

In the story I am looking for, the MC has darker hair. Her father was heartless and didn't care about her and didn't believe she was his daughter and that the evil blonde girl truly was. They were waiting for them to be blessed with power, but the MC somehow didn't activate her powers, although she was sure she would get them. Instead, the fake daughter gained powers somehow. The MC is his true daughter, but he was counting on whomever got the powers being his true daughter and the MC didn't get blessed with powers for some reason.

After this, the father, believing that he was right about the MC not being his daughter all along, eagerly took her to a dungeon and sentenced her to death for pretending to be royalty, I think. Her little brother tried to have her defend herself, but she had already given up, completely stunned by the trap she fell into. The fake daughter was behind all of the madness, even getting all of the MC's maids, butler, her father, etc. to turn on her.

Right as the MC was executed, she woke up a few days/months(?) into the past, before the evil blonde girl who claimed the royal man is her father, came to the palace and destroyed everything. In the new life she has, she spends it changing her cold demeanor towards everyone. She gets closer to her maids and makes friends, even sneaking out to gamble at a casino. She falls in love easily, she is mature, independent, and doesn't care about her father anymore. She never runs to him, trying to get him to love and accept her and because of this, the father suddenly starts wanting the MC's love and attention.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The exact same story as what?  If you're referring to another question on the site you should include a link to it. (You can just [edit] your post and paste the URL into it.)  When did you read this?

Comment: Sorry that was an accident, I wasn't replying to anything I am asking a question so I edited it. Hopefully to new edit helps.

Comment: Was this in full colour? And, what colour was the MC's hair?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: So far no one has even replied to identify the story yet.. but I think I remember the mc girl had long dark hair and the evil fake daughter has wavy blonde hair. I'm not completely sure because I am going of a month memory. ): The father also is blond and looks similar to fake daughter whilst mc(blood daughter) had blue eyes just like the father and looks like her dead mother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[I Am the Real One](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/joe0ehi/i-am-the-real-one)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> A prophecy foretold that the Grand Duke would only have one water elementalist born from him. Though she lacks her father's affection, Keira knows she’s destined for those powers. But after years of doing what was right and proper of a noble, she's executed after the conniving Cosette appears, claiming to be the Grand Duke's real daughter. But then—Keira wakes up with newfound purpose: make changes, allies, and even friends before it's too late. Will it be enough before Cosette hatches her plot?

The day the Grand Duke, Ludwig Parvis, was granted his title, the Oracle prophesised that he'd have a single daughter; a saintess blessed by the water spirits with powers that would save the continent from a crisis.

His firstborn daughter, Kiara, lost her mother at a young age and yearned for his love. She studied hard to win his praise, but he failed to show her any interest or affection, and her insistence on being proper and dignified made her seem cold and aloof to everyone else.

When Kiara was 18, a girl named Cosette Weinberg appeared, claiming to be the Duke's eldest daughter by a previous wife. While the Duke was unsure of this, he decided to give her a chance to prove herself and allowed her to move in.

Over the next two years, Cosette manipulated the Duke and his staff into looking more kindly upon her than they did on Kiara, and when Cosette eventually manifested water powers, Kiara was accused of being a criminal and imprisoned, awaiting execution.

While imprisoned, Kiara was visited by her younger brother, Zik, who suggested they run away together, but she didn't want him facing criminal charges as well, and told him to leave. She was subsequently executed by guillotine.

Then Kiara woke up in bed, initially thinking she was in the afterlife. After speaking with Zik though, she realised she was now in the past, two months prior to Cosette's arrival.

Having been given another chance, Kiara resolved to live her life differently. Instead of trying so hard to impress her father, she decided to spend more time with others, and let her hair down more, becoming a more fun person to be around.

[image] [image]

Comment: YES!!!!! I'VE BEEN SEARCHING FOR THIS, YOU ARE MY HERO!!!!!!